# How to create a matrix of bytes Golang

Tags: go, matrix, slice

I can't find how to create a matrix of bytes in Golang.

```
test := {
{"6",".",".","1","9","5",".",".","."},
{".","9","8",".",".",".",".","6","."},
{"8",".",".",".","6",".",".",".","3"},
{"4",".",".","8",".","3",".",".","1"},
{"7",".",".",".","2",".",".",".","6"},
{".","6",".",".",".",".","2","8","."},
{".",".",".","4","1","9",".",".","5"},
{".",".",".",".","8",".",".","7","9"}}
```

> syntax error: unexpected {, expecting expression 
>   syntax error: unexpected { at end of statement

Or second way I used

```
test := make([][]byte, 9);
test = append(test, []byte{"5","3",".",".","7",".",".",".","."})
test = append(test, []byte{"6",".",".","1","9","5",".",".","."})
```

> cannot convert "5" (type untyped string) to type byte

Comment: Use single quotes like `'5'` and take the Tour of Go.

Comment: I tried to use single quotes and got the same error

Comment: Did you take the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1)? It answers basic syntax questions like this one. Do that, and if you still have problems, come back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example misses the type of the [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals).

Since you used `string` values, this works (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/jBdBLOjoJL_m)):

```
test := [][]string{
    {"6", ".", ".", "1", "9", "5", ".", ".", "."},
    {".", "9", "8", ".", ".", ".", ".", "6", "."},
    {"8", ".", ".", ".", "6", ".", ".", ".", "3"},
    {"4", ".", ".", "8", ".", "3", ".", ".", "1"},
    {"7", ".", ".", ".", "2", ".", ".", ".", "6"},
    {".", "6", ".", ".", ".", ".", "2", "8", "."},
    {".", ".", ".", "4", "1", "9", ".", ".", "5"},
    {".", ".", ".", ".", "8", ".", ".", "7", "9"},
}
```

If you want a "byte matrix", use constant literals that may be assigned to a variable of `byte` type, e.g. a [rune literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals) (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/3TmLMlObrIL)):

```
test := [][]byte{
    {'6', '.', '.', '1', '9', '5', '.', '.', '.'},
    {'.', '9', '8', '.', '.', '.', '.', '6', '.'},
    {'8', '.', '.', '.', '6', '.', '.', '.', '3'},
    {'4', '.', '.', '8', '.', '3', '.', '.', '1'},
    {'7', '.', '.', '.', '2', '.', '.', '.', '6'},
    {'.', '6', '.', '.', '.', '.', '2', '8', '.'},
    {'.', '.', '.', '4', '1', '9', '.', '.', '5'},
    {'.', '.', '.', '.', '8', '.', '.', '7', '9'},
}
```

You can achieve the same if you enumerate rows as strings, and use a `[]byte()` [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) to convert rows to `[]byte` (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/OW_zN9WuYyO)):

```
test := [][]byte{
    []byte("6..195..."),
    []byte(".98....6."),
    []byte("8...6...3"),
    []byte("4..8.3..1"),
    []byte("7...2...6"),
    []byte(".6....28."),
    []byte("...419..5"),
    []byte("....8..79"),
}
```

This last version may be more pleasing to eyes and easier to modify, but note that it only works if you use ASCII characters in the rows, as characters higher than 127 have multi-bytes in UTF-8 encoding (which is how Go stores strings in memory), so converting such `string` to `[]byte` will result in more bytes than characters it has.